# Facebook Login Warning

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I get the following notice while testing facebook login:

> You are using a display type of 'page' in a small browser window or popup. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively, use display type 'popup' if you have special requirements precluding you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application.

Here is the JavaScript I believe is responsible:

```html
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<?php echo $this->getAppId() ?>', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo $this->getLocale() ?>/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    function greet(id){
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            var src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+id+'/picture';
            $$('.welcome-msg')[0].insert('<img height="20" src="'+src+'"/>');
        });
    }

    function fblogin(){
        try {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'connected') {
                    var url = '<?php echo $this->getLoginUrl() ?>';
                    setLocation(url);
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    alert('<?php echo $this->__('Please, approve our application') ?>');
                } else {
                    // user is not logged in
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }, {scope:'email'});
        } catch (err) {
            fblogin();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please make sure that popup width should not go beyond 580px and height 400px. If you are making sure of these things, warning will go away.

Comment: How do I set the width and height?

Comment: window.open('example.html', 'page', 'width=580,height=400');